# Sabre - "EndTransactionLLSRQ: NEED CUSTOMER NUMBER - USE DK"

Tags: passenger, record, sabre

I am using Sabre REST API to create Passenger Name record (PNR) and I am getting an error `"EndTransactionLLSRQ: NEED CUSTOMER NUMBER - USE DK"`

I was reading a documentation for create PNR and I didn't find where can I set Customer number, maybe someone know where this inforation is set?

REST API: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/

Full response: https://pastebin.com/YqPuz4mk

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem you need to set `CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ.TravelItineraryAddInfo.CustomerInfo.CustomerIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the Agency setup. Not all API Agency customers are required to enter a DK customer number when creating a PNR.